# Kivy: set ID in TwoLineListItem

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I have this code that reads the files I have in my storage, and It returns in TwoLineListItem.

Example: if I have 2 files will return 2 TwoLineListItem.

```
def listarReceitaDoce(self):
    dir1 = '/storage/emulated/0/Receitas/BOLOS E TORTAS DOCES'
    os.chdir(dir1)
    for file in os.listdir():
        if file.endswith('.txt'):
            file_path = f"{dir1}/{file}"
            with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
                lines = f.readlines()   
                lines = [line.strip() for line in lines]
                st_idx = lines.index("receita")
                ed_idx = lines.index("ingredientes")
                l = lines[st_idx:ed_idx]
                self.root.ids.telaselecionada.ids.mostraReceita.add_widget(TwoLineListItem(text = str(l[1]), secondary_text = str(l[3])))
```

I'm trying to set an ID on each TwoLineListItem, so when I press the TwoLineListItem, I can read the exactly file with their informations.

Example: if I press the first TwoLineListItem, it open the first file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parent widgets have the property `ids`. This property is a dict that contains all the referneced children (all the children with ids).
In order to add an `id` to a bunch of objects in a `for` loop, check the following example:

```
parent = GridLayout(cols=1)
for i in range(10): #Iterate 10 times
    btn = Button(text = f'Button {i}') #Create item
    parent.add_widget(btn) #Add item
    parent.ids["Button"+str(i)] = btn #Add the object to the dict with a key.
    
print(parent.ids) #This will print all the button's ids
```

Now, in your code:

```
i = 1 #Create a counter to reference the objects
for file in os.listdir():
        if file.endswith('.txt'):
            file_path = f"{dir1}/{file}"
            with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
                lines = f.readlines()   
                lines = [line.strip() for line in lines]
                st_idx = lines.index("receita")
                ed_idx = lines.index("ingredientes")
                l = lines[st_idx:ed_idx]
                item = TwoLineListItem(text = str(l[1]), secondary_text = str(l[3])) #Create your item
                self.root.ids.telaselecionada.ids.mostraReceita.add_widget(item) #Add your widget to parent
                self.root.ids.telaselecionada.ids.mostraReceita.ids['item '+str(i)] = item #Create a new key in the dict and givi it the value of your current item
                i+=1 #Increment the counter
```

Comment: Thanks man. It worked. What I was doing is set ID with self.root.ids, not like this way. ..