# How to add OneLineIconListItem with ID to MDSelectionList in KivyMD?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivymd

I'm trying to set an ID for each item I add to a `MDSelectionList` in KivyMD, but then, when I try to access the ID, it's empty. I have this code:

```
for player in players:
    kv_string = '''
OneLineIconListItem:
    id: '{id}'
    text: '{name}'
    IconLeftWidget:
        icon: 'circle-outline'
        pos_hint: {{'center_y': .5}}
    '''.format(
        id=player['id']
        name=player['name']
    )
    self.all_player_list.add_widget(
        Builder.load_string(kv_string)
    )
```

And then, when I try to access the ID of a `OneIconListItem`, it returns nothing. However, if I put the player ID in the `OneIconListItem` `text` parameter (instead of in the `id` one), I can get the ID.

```
selected_players = self.all_player_list.get_selected_list_items()
for selected_player in selected_players:
    player_id = selected_player.children[1].id
    player_name = selected_player.children[1].text
```

In the previous code, `selected_player.children` returns `[<kivymd.uix.selection.selection.SelectionIconCheck object at 0x7f7b88bd6ad0>, <kivymd.uix.list.list.OneLineIconListItem object at 0x7f7b891f6450>]`. So I'm using it to access each `OneLineIconListItem` selected. But `player_id` contains nothing. However, `player_name` has the value of the `text` parameter stored rigthly.

Does anyone how to manage what I want? Basically, I have a list of objects (players) with several attributes, and I want to show the name of the players in the list, but have access to their IDs too, to perform SQL queries in a secure way.

**EDIT**

I've also tried the answer by @Edher Carbajal, it will work in a standard `MDList`, but I'm working with a `MDSelectionList`, which returns `<kivymd.uix.selection.selection.SelectionItem>` objects.

[Kivy: set ID in TwoLineListItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70871256/kivy-set-id-in-twolinelistitem)